# create something like a for in swi prolog

Tags: for-loop, prolog, permutation

i want to create something like a for in swi prolog

```
for(int i=1;i<8;i++)
{
for(int j=1;j<11;j++)
{
//do something with i and j
//finish(i,j) in swi prolog 
if any finish is true write a message
}
}
```

i don't have any ideea how to generate all this permutation i,j in swi prolog please help me.

swi prolog code:

```
finish :-
        finishL1(i,j),

    write('Game Over, Player1 won!'),nl,
    start.
```

i want finish do check all finishL1(i,j) permutation like in above for, if any finishL1 is true then write

Answer (score 2):

Loops in Prolog are problematic, because variables cannot be reassigned. You could try

```
forall(between(1,8,I),
   forall(between(1,11,J), (
      % place your code
   )
),
```

but beware that [forall](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=forall/2)/2 'release' variables when done. Please read the documentation, it's fairly explicative.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution, taken from the Logtalk standard library:

```
:- meta_predicate(forto_aux(*, *, *, *, 0)).
forto_aux(Count, First, Last, Increment, Goal) :-
    (   First =< Last ->
        \+ \+ (Count = First, call(Goal)),
        Next is First + Increment,
        forto_aux(Count, Next, Last, Increment, Goal)
    ;   true
    ).

:- meta_predicate(forto(*, *, 0)).
forto(FirstExp, LastExp, Goal) :-
    First is FirstExp,
    Last is LastExp,
    forto_aux(_, First, Last, 1, Goal).
```

For other loop variations and related predicates, see:

https://github.com/LogtalkDotOrg/logtalk3/blob/master/library/loopp.lgt (interface)
https://github.com/LogtalkDotOrg/logtalk3/blob/master/library/loop.lgt  (implementation)

Some other Prolog compiler, e.g. B-Prolog and ECLiPSe, provide native support for loops. But there isn't an official or de facto standard for these constructs.